# Recursive CTE help - how do you code this non-hierarchal sequence?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a recursive CTE for a table that does not have a hierarchy. Meaning that there is no NULL in the family of IDs that are related.

For example table looks like this:

So it looks like this:

```
AccountID Account_RelationshipID
--------------------------------    
 1                       2
 2                       4
 4                       6
 6                      11
11                       1
15                      17
17                      19
19                      15
```

So 1 relates to 2. 2 relates to 4. 4 relates to 6. 6 relates to 11. And then 11 loops back to ID of 1.

Then there is a new family. 15 relates to 17. 17 relates to 19. and then 19 goes back to 15.

There is also a separate Account_Detail table that has the account date:

```
AccountID   AccountName   AccountDate
-------------------------------------
 1          Dave          1/1/2012
 2          Dave          1/1/2013
 4          Dave          1/1/2014
 6          Dave          1/1/2015
11          Dave          1/1/2016
15          Paul          7/1/2015
17          Paul          7/1/2016
19          Paul          7/1/2017
```

I tried writing this as my code:

```
WITH C AS
(
    SELECT
        AR.AccountID,
        AR.Account_RelationshipID,
        AD.AccountDate
    FROM 
        Account_Relationship AR
    INNER JOIN 
        Account_Detail AD ON AD.AccountID = AR.AccountID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        AR2.AccountID,
        AR2.Account_RelationshipID,
        AD.AccountDate
    FROM 
        Account_Relationship AR2
    INNER JOIN 
        Account_Detail AD2 ON AD2.Account_ID = AR2.Account_ID
    INNER JOIN 
        C ON C.AccountID = AR2.Account_relationshipID
    WHERE 
        AD.AccountDate < AD2.AccountDate
)
```

Obviously this code is totally wrong. This is as far as I've gotten. This code will loop infinitely.

I was thinking I could break the loop by adding a function that states when the AccountDate of the next AccountID in the loop is less than the AccountDate of the last AccountID, to break the loop and go to the next one.

Also, how do you get it to go to the next "family" of accountIDs in the loops (Paul in this case)? All the videos and tutorials I've seen about Recursive CTEs just teach how to do it for one family - usually with a hierarchical structure that breaks at NULL as well.

Help!!

Comment: Does each accountname have a single loop or can there be multiple loops? If each accountname is a single loop, I think I might assign an arbitrary row number (partitioned by accountname) then use `where rn = 1` as the anchor for the recursive cte, with the subsequent unions joining on ` and rn <> 1` if that makes sense. If you can have multiple loops for each accountname this gets a bit more difficult to do.

Comment: The desired output of your query, how it should look like?

Comment: `how do you get it to go to the next "family" of accountID` . Isn't `AccountName` of ` Account_Detail` determines the Family ?

Comment: Can we simply assume that id Joined ID is less than ID (1 < 11 and 15 < 19) then we could stop? Otherwise you need a column for "head pointer".

Comment: I think we can safely assume that the ids will always increment. So when the next number in the loop is less than previous, the loop should break and go to the next family.

Comment: The result set should Group and list all Account IDs that are related to each other in a table - with a column that identifies the group. Row number would work. 

For example: Row number 1 would list 1, 2, 4, 6, 11. Row number 2 would list 15, 17, 19, and so forth.